# dingo api laravel 5.1 reflection exception error

Tags: php, rest, laravel, dingo-api

I got the error immediately I added the route group to the following group

```
<?php

$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->version('v1', function ($api) {

    $api->post('auth/login', 'App\Api\V1\Controllers\AuthController@login');
    $api->post('auth/signup', 'App\Api\V1\Controllers\AuthController@signup');
    $api->post('auth/recovery', 'App\Api\V1\Controllers\AuthController@recovery');
    $api->post('auth/reset', 'App\Api\V1\Controllers\AuthController@reset');

    // example of protected route
    $api->get('protected', ['middleware' => ['api.auth'], function () {     
        return \App\User::all();
    }]);

    // example of free route
    $api->get('free', function() {
        return \App\User::all();
    });

    $api->group(['middleware' => 'api.auth'], function ($api) {
        $api->post('driver/store', 'App/Api/V1/Controllers/DriverController@store');
        $api->post('driver', 'App/Api/V1/Controllers/DriverController@index');
    });
});
```

if i should remove the route group, the the other routes would work, i have checked the namespace declaration in my controller and it was correct, did composer autoload and yet none has worked for me yet.

Comment: Could you post the full content of the exception?

Comment: reflection exception the class 'App/Api/V1/Controllers/DriverController' cannot be found.

Comment: Looked at this again think your `/`'s should actually be `\\`

Comment: oh..thanks i've looked at the code so many times and didn't notice the simple syntax error...i will go and try it out now.